# How to show a custom button or component inside DevExtereme tagbox?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, devextreme

I am using tag-box in my angular application.

lets say I have a component called TagboxComponent where I use my tagbox element. and another component called scrollButtonsComponent. in my scrollButtons component I have 2 buttons which helps me scroll the container of tagbox a given amount.

In my tagbox I have a dropdown button as well. when I add the scrollButtonscomponent into my TagboxComponent the scroll buttons are shown on the right of the dropDown button.

I want the scroll buttons to be on the left of the dropDown button.
here is what I have:

```
<dx-tag-box #tagBoxElement id="myTagContainer" class='baseInput myTagContainer' (onValueChanged)="onValueChanged($event)"
        [dataSource]="options" [value]="value" displayExpr="text" valueExpr="value" [placeholder]="''" [focusStateEnabled]="false"
        [openOnFieldClick]="false" [showSelectionControls]="true" [showDropDownButton]="true"  tagTemplate="tagTemplate">

        <div *dxTemplate="let tagData of 'tagTemplate'" class="dx-tag-content tag">
            <span>
                {{tagData.text}}
            </span>
        </div>

        <div *dxTemplate="let data of 'dropDownButton'">
            <button>drop</imageElement>
        </div>

        <dxi-button name="dropDown"></dxi-button>

    </dx-tag-box>

    <scroll-buttons [scrollContainer]="scrollableContainer" [scrollAmount]="tagHeight"></scroll-buttons>
```

If I add the scroll-buttons inside tagBox it gets hidden and it never is visible.